# Bash string replacing , find parent path

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I wanted to do a string replacing with bash , which will find the parent path from the current running program's path.

So i tried to removing everything , from the last '/' to the end with regular expression:

`echo ${0#/.*#}`

But it's not working , and please don't let me use external programs , it's better getting everything with bash...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] a="/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/file.txt"
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo ${a%/*}
/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp
```

Answer (score 4):

> So i tried to removing everything , from the last '/' to the end with regular expression:

```
> echo ${0#/.*#}
```

That is not a regular expression. Besides, you don't want the hash character (which removes a prefix), but a % sign (which removes suffix). In either case, that second hash character is not meant to be there (This is /not/ a regular expression. See the PARAMETER EXPANSION chapter in your bash manual).

You could use

```
echo ${a%/*}
```

to print the directory (but this breaks if "$a" does not contain a slash), or

```
echo ${a##*/}
```

to print the file (note the double `##` to remove the longest matching prefix) (but this would break if "$a" was itself a directory and you wanted only that last component).

It's better to use the existing commands

```
dirname "$a"
```

and

```
basename "$a"
```

, respectively